# how to stop twitter login from displaying Undefined index: oauth_token and Undefined index: oauth_token_secret

Tags: php, twitter

This is the function on twitteroauth.php file

I tried various examples for login in with twitter from my site, but I always get the same error

> Undefined index: oauth_token in D:\wamp\www\login-with-twitter\oauth\twitteroauth.php on line 73

don't know what to do

```
 function getRequestToken($oauth_callback) {
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['oauth_callback'] = $oauth_callback; 
    $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->requestTokenURL(), 'GET', $parameters);
    $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);// line 73
    return $token;
  }
```

And also

> Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in D:\wamp\www\login-with-twitter\index.php on line 34
>    Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in D:\wamp\www\login-with-twitter\index.php on line 35

```
  if(isset($_GET['connect']) && $_GET['connect']=='twitter'){

            $connection = new TwitterOAuth($this->consumer_key, $this->consumer_secret);// Key and Sec
            $request_token = $connection->getRequestToken($this->oauth_callback);// Retrieve Temporary credentials. 

            $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token']; //line 34
            $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret']; //line 35


            switch ($connection->http_code) {
              case 200:    $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token); // Redirect to authorize page.
                header('Location: ' . $url); 
                break;
              default:
                echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
    }
        }
```

Comment: It seems you are not getting access token or secret, try to print `$request_token` using `print_r` function. If it is empty that means your code does not get access token.

Comment: Array ( [ "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob' /oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=http://localhost/login-with-twitter/twitter/callback.php [amp;oauth_consumer_key] => IISm8JST1RWTkqDkhMwq2T5tg [amp;oauth_nonce] => ca526a8a28626b0e518ae9186d706dd1 [amp;oauth_signature] => /SvBLbi8G5w5O56wanUOJ5dHp3U= [amp;oauth_signature_method] => HMAC-SHA1 [amp;oauth_timestamp] => 1481698943 [amp;oauth_version] => 1.0 ) Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.

Comment: this is result  of print_r($request_token);

Comment: As it seems it does not contain `$request_token['oauth_token'];`  thatswhy you get error.

Comment: please tell me what to do so that it works well

Comment: At first add Twitter tag with your question. I have not use Twitter OAuth api, so I cannot help. Add the tag maybe someone will help you.

Comment: ok @kumar and thankew :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you define your twitter

> > `consumer key`
> >     `consumer secret` 
> >     their is also an option of : `oauth callback` .
> >     please make sure you have same callback url as on your app setting `callback url`
> >     give it as `https://dev.twitter.com/`